# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{42}{(i+1)^3}$ converges.

Tags: limits

I am having some difficulties proving this statement. Any help would be appreciatted. I have proved that $\left (\frac{1}{2^i} \right)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is summable, however, I couldn't prove it for this one.

P.S. I am not sure if the formula is readable. It is the sequence $42/((i+1)^3)$ ($i$ is an element of the Nat. numbers) and I need to show that it is summable. Sorry if it is not readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by summable, but if you mean that the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{42}{(i+1)^3} $ converges, then it does.

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{42}{(i+1)^3}= 42\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+1)^3}< 42\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}$ which converges. Than by the Direct comparison test, our series converges.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. It's just that in German we say, that if a sequence is summable then it converges, that's what causes the misunderstanding. Thank you!

Comment: And the sum is $42\cdot(\zeta(3)-1)$...